# Recommendation letter sent from non-institutional email

Tags: recommendation-letter

Would it hurt the student's evaluation, if I were to send their recommendation letter from my gmail account as opposed to the institutional?

I use my gmail account for all my correspondence, it is listed on all my papers, university website, etc.

Comment: I'm not an expert, but I would try to use my institutional email for such correspondence "just in case".

Comment: Related - http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/13845/letter-of-recommendation-from-an-unofficial-college-email-id

Comment: Depending on where you are, there may also be legal implications requiring you to use institutional e-mail for institutional business.

Comment: @JackAidley: ship's already sailed on that since the questioner doesn't use the institutional address for anything at the moment...

Comment: I’m slightly surprised that no current answers are concretely answering the question asked.  This site has lots of users who have been on hiring or admissions committees; surely one of them is able to give their experience of the topic, whether it’s “No, I never notice what email address referees use” or “Yes, it’s often discussed, since it can be a mechanism for attempted fraud.”

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't say what the recommendation letter is for, but it's generally not a big deal for academic letters in my experience.  For industry letters, many businesses also use gmail, so it will probably not be looked on too strangely there either.

However, a plain text letter from gmail does look less professional than a one on official letterhead, so you might use your department letterhead.  If you want to use gmail, you can also cc a copy of the letter to your instituional address to "certify" that you are who you claim to be.

Comment: I intended to send my letter as an attachment, which would have the official letterhead of the department. However, I really don't think the letterhead is hard to come by, am I missing something?

Comment: @user3209815 I am saying a plain text email recommendation from a personal email address looks considerably less professional than a pdf of a signed letter on official letterhead.  As in you went though the small amount of effort to make your letter look professional rather than putting just the minimum amount of effort into your letter.  If I see a professional looking letter, whether it is sent from gmail or not won't make much of a difference to me.

Answer (score 14):

I use my gmail, but gmail has the capability to manage the sender addresses. You should authenticate your gmail to send from your institutional address. The recipient will then have the confirmation that you are indeed who you say you are, as gmail will have already done the authentication.

The authenticator in gmail  has the ability to either use the SMTP server of your institution to send (if your systems team permits it), where gmail is then acting as the mail client, or it can use the `From` headers to indicate your authenticated affiliation.

If you were doing it properly you could manage all your email through the gmail account and choose whichever outgoing account and sending method you choose. This is what I do, for the several academic institutional affiliations I possess.

So in summary: you can have it both ways. You can use gmail for official institutional correspondence and you can use the options provided in gmail to choose which of your attributions any particular email uses. It is appropriate to badge emails for official correspondence, such as letters of recommendation, with your institutional addresses. I would   suggest not using a personal email addresses for business purposes, but using the tools properly you can customise your environment in a professional manner.

Comment: Oh, right.  I forgot about this when I answered.  (I chose not to do this personally.)

Comment: +1. In case it's not clear from this answer: Once you've demonstrated to Gmail that you have access to send messages from a certain e-mail address, you will subsequently have the *option* to use that address when sending an e-mail.

Comment: Doesn't actually answer the question...

Comment: He clearly says, "I use Gmail". I took it to mean that he uses gmail to send recommendation letters, but if you were still worried that you could have your gmail send emails using your institutional email. That way regardless of which you use it looks professional.

Comment: @Mehrdad Does, actually. The answer says "You can use Gmail to send from your institution email." That's definitely an answer.

Comment: @QPayTaxes: unless I'm blind or dyslexic, I think the question was "Would it hurt the student's evaluation, if I were to send their recommendation letter from my gmail account as opposed to the institutional?" to which the answer is either yes or no.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes: No, it really doesn’t answer the question!  It says a lot about what the referee’s different options are, but nothing about how (if at all) the receiving committee will be influenced the use of a non-instutitional address, or at least nothing more specific than “It is appropriate to badge emails for official correspondence […] with your institutional addresses.”  It’s very helpful and informative, but it doesn’t say anything concrete addressing the actual question asked.

Comment: @PLL Oh, I see what you mean. I think it's answering the X to this question's Y -- that is, saying "your problem isn't really a problem". In my mind, that's a real answer.

Comment: I assumed the OP was aware of this Gmail feature and still wanted to use a Gmail address.

Comment: @svavil absolutely. it is not my intention to mask the email client I'm using. the recipient will see xyz@gmail.com instead of xyz@institution.edu as the sender.

Comment: @Brian Tompsett I must concur with Mehrdad and PLL, as it is, your answer points out that you don't suggest "using a personal email addresses for business purposes". Would you mind expanding it? Do you have experience with people who used their gmail accounts and got themselves or others in trouble because of that?

Answer (score 6):

For other purpose, I recently try to confirm that some professor X was indeed employed by University Y. This search taught me that some universities do not have directories for their faculty member or any other way to confirm online that professor X is a real researcher.

For this reason, I would strongly suggest to use your institutional email, in case there is doubt about your affiliation or existence.